# Repeated Measures ANOVA vs multiple Univariate ANOVAs

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have a dataset coming from a psychological experiment where each participant is rating faces of 5 different emotions presented randomly. So the emotion category is a within-subject variable and DV is reaction time.  For the between-subject, I have two grouping variables: having gene X and having condition Y.

I would normally go with the 2x2x5 repeated-measures ANOVA. However, I am not interested in the differences between each emotion category, so any within-subject contrast is of no interest. Rather, I am interested in whether there is a main effect of X or Y or their interaction for each emotion type. Moreover, SPSS does not produce 2x2 post-hoc table for repeated measures anova. So, I would like to know if running separate univariate 2x2 ANOVAs for each emotion category is feasible here. Something like;

gene x condition ANOVA on the reaction time of happiness.
gene x condition ANOVA on the reaction time of sadness.
gene x condition ANOVA on the reaction time of fear.
.....

Am I violating/missing something by not using repeated measures? Do I need to make some corrections?

Also, any suggestion for an alternative approach is more than welcomed.